# Responsive Image with Clip Path- HTML

Tags: css, html

I need a suggestion for creating an Image with clip path. This image looks like slightly low height in right corner side. Actually I done this by using clip path but while applying border style I got the issue with border radius in right corner. can anyone please give some suggestion.

```css
html {
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 80%;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wholediv img {
  clip-path: polygon(5% 5%, 95% 10%, 95% 93%, 5% 93%);
}

.wholediv {
  display: block;
  width: 38%;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 5%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<div class="wholediv">
  <img src="http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/531265main_iss027e007014_1600_800-600.jpg" alt="" width="100%" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `border-top-right-radius` with two values for this corner. Top indent use `%`, right indent `px`:

```css
html {
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 80%;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wholediv img {
  clip-path: polygon(5% 5%, 95% 10%, 95% 93%, 5% 93%);
}

.wholediv {
  display: block;
  width: 38%;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 5%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  border-radius: 16px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25% 16px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<div class="wholediv">
  <img src="http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/531265main_iss027e007014_1600_800-600.jpg" alt="" width="100%" />
</div>
```